# Не выводится рубрики/теги/выбор изображения в gutenberg редакторе Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, gutenberg

Столкнулся с проблемой, что при переезде двух сайтов на другой хостинг, пропала возможность выбора рубрик/тегов и изображения именно в панели записей в gutenberg редакторе. В classic редакторе все работает, но это неудобно и костыль.

Выгружал сайты на localhost, там все работает, на старом хостинге тоже работало.

Значит проблема со стороны хостинга, что не могут обрабатываться запросы и не выводятся рубрики с тегами. Пробовал новый домен регистрировать и к нему стандартную чистую тему, тоже не работает.

Весь интернет перелопатил, решения не нашел, может кто сталкивался с подобным?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/767561/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B0-wordpress/767562